# Data alignment in Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am writhing a code to generate a excel file having the data sourced by calling API and correlate those to get desired result.

basically taking input from one database and search that in others and fetch related information.

The 4 databases have below data :

```
EEp
---------------------
{u'data': [{u'_id': u'5c30702c8ca9f51da8178df4',
            u'encap': u'vlan-24',
            u'ip': u'7.12.12.16',
            u'mac': u'5B:P9:01:9E:42:08'}]}

PathEp
-----------
{u'data': [{u'_id': u'5c54a81a8ca9f51da84ae08e',
            u'paths': u'paths-1507',
            u'endpoint': u'eth1/10',
            u'cep': u'5B:P9:01:9E:42:08',
            u'tenant': u'ESX'}]}
ip4_address
-----------------------

{u'data': [{u'Allocation': u'Build_Reserved',
            u'address': u'7.12.12.16',
            u'name': u'fecitrix-1',
            u'state': u'RESERVED'}]}
asset
---------------
{u'data': [{u'_id': u'57ccce8110dd54f02881fedc', 
            u'client': u'CES',
            u'hostname': u'fecitrix-1'
            u'os_team': u'Window'}]}
```

Logic:

1. If "mac" of EEp and "cep" of PathEp is same than take "encap","ip" ,"mac"
      "paths" ,'endpoint","cep" and "tenant" (these values need to be exported
       to excel)
2. Take ip of EEp and search in "ip4_address" 
   and get the "name" from ip4_address ( name need to be exported to excel).
3. If "name" of ip4_address is equal to "hostname" of database "asset" then take 
     "client" and "os_team" ( export that to excel)

I have written the script but not getting the desired result.

```
def get_host_details(self):
    data = {
        "find": {
            "hostname": self.controller
            },
    "projection":{
        "tenant": 1,
        "paths": 1,
        "endpoint":1
        }
    }
    host_details = self.post("https://database.app.com/api/data/devices/PathEp/find", data)
    #print host_details
    hosts = []
    for record in host_details:
        if "mig" not in record["endpoint"]:
            hosts.append(record)
    return hosts


def get_ipaddress(self, controller):

    host_record = {"tenant": "UNKNOWN",
                   "paths": "UNKNOWN",
                   "endpoint": "UNKNOWN",
                   "ip": "UNKNOWN",
                   "mac": "UNKNOWN",
                   "encap": "UNKNOWN"}
    data = {
        "find": {
            "hostname": controller,
            "ip": {
                "$ne": "0.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "projection": {
            "ip": 1,
            "mac":1,
            "encap":1,
        }
    }
    endpoints = self.post("https://database.app.com/api/data/devices/EEp/find", data)
    IPAM = self.get_dns()
    print endpoints
    host_details = self.get_host_details()
    host_details_record = []
    for record in endpoints:
        for host in host_details:
            if record["mac"] == host["cep"]:
                host_record = {"tenant": host["tenant"],
                               "paths": host["paths"],                                  
                               "endpoint": host["endpoint"],
                               "ip": record["ip"],
                               "mac": record["mac"],
                               "encap": record["encap"]}
                host_details_record.append(host_record)
    self.get_excel(host_details_record)


def get_dns(self, endpoints):
    ip_dns_record = []
    for each_endpoint in endpoints:
        data = {
            "find":
                {
                    "address": {
                        "$eq": each_endpoint["ip"]
                    },
                },
            "projection":
                {
                    "name": 1
                }

        }

        dns_record = {"client":"UNKNOWN",
                      "os_team":"UNKNOWN",


        ipam_record = self.post("https://database.app.com/api/data/"
                                "internal/ip4_address/find", data)
        if ipam_record:
            dns_record["ip_address"] = each_endpoint["ip"]
            dns_record["hostname"] = ipam_record[0]["name"]
            dns_record = self.get_remedy_details(ipam_record[0]["name"],
                                                 dns_record)
            ip_dns_record.append(dns_record)
        else:
            dns_record["ip_address"] = each_endpoint["ip"]
            dns_record["hostname"] = "UNKNOWN"
            ip_dns_record.append(dns_record)
    self.get_excel(ip_dns_record)



def get_remedy_details(self, hostname, dns_record):

    data = {
        "find":
            {
                "hostname": hostname.upper(),

            }
    }
    remedy_data = self.post("https://database.app.com/api/data/internal/asset/find", data)
    print(remedy_data)
    #remedy_data = remedy_data["data"]
    if remedy_data:
        dns_record["client"] = remedy_data[0].get("client","UNKNOWN")
        dns_record["os_team"] = remedy_data[0].get("os_team", "UNKNOWN")

    else:
        dns_record["client"] = "UNKNOWN"
        dns_record["os_team"] = "UNKNOWN"

    return dns_record

def get_excel(self, ip_dns_record):
    filename = self.controller + ".xls"
    excel_file = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = excel_file.add_sheet('HOSTLIST')
    sheet.write(0, 0, "IP Address")
    sheet.write(0, 1, "HostName")
    sheet.write(0, 2, "Client")
    sheet.write(0, 3, "OS Team")

    for count in xrange(1, len(ip_dns_record)+1):
        sheet.write(count, 0,ip_dns_record[count - 1]["ip_address"])
        sheet.write(count, 1,ip_dns_record[count - 1]["hostname"])
        sheet.write(count, 2,ip_dns_record[count - 1]["client"])
        sheet.write(count, 3,ip_dns_record[count - 1]["os_team"])

    excel_file.save(filename)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    controller = sys.argv[1]
    OBJ = ACIHostList(controller)
    print "SCRIPT COMPLETED"
```

No idea where I am going wrong and what needs to be done .

Comment: your post is very "extended", you need to narrow your code and description to what we need to help you with. if you are having problems extracting data from a DB then focus on it. if your problem is to write the data to an excel file then focus on that.

Comment: I am struggling with Logic : 2 to be incorporate to script

Comment: you are having problems with retrieving the name from ip4 or exporting the `name` to excel? what do you mean by exporting `name` to excel? en excel with a single cell with the name in it?

Comment: I am exporting all the details to excel.. similarly “name” from ip4_address should go to excel along with other details ( ip, mac, encap etc) respectively..

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves too much out. You should include all errors that you get. You should also comment your code as well so we can understand what you are trying to achieve in each step.

This is not an answer but something to try:

Rather than trying to wrap your head around a module like excel, wright your data to a simple CSV file. A CSV file can be opened up in excel and it formats correctly but is a lot easier to create.

```
import csv

data = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
with open("file.csv", "w+") as csv_file:
    create_csv = csv.writer(csv_file)
    create_csv .writerows(data)
```

simply grab all your data into a 2D list and using the above code dump it into a file so you can easily read it.
check the output of the file and see if you are getting the data you expect.

If you are not getting the desired data into this CSV file then there is an issue with your database queries.